# Set-PnPField -Values @{DependantLookupInternalName=??}

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, site-column, pnp-powershell

Hello SharePoint Peoples,

So I am trying to figure out how to use a lot of the PnP Commands. Getting hung up on `Set-PnPField`. I have a column already created, and I can `Get-PnPField` and read it's properties. The property I am interested in editing is `DependantLookupInternalNames` which look to be the related columns that will be added to a given list if the Lookup column is added to a list.

I know that you can:

```
$siteField = Get-PnPField -Identity ThisField
if ($siteField) {
    [xml]$schemaXml = $siteField.SchemaXml
    $schemaXml.Field.ShowField = "NewShowField"
    Set-PnPField -Identity ThisField-Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
}
```

BUT the `DependantLookupInternalNames` does not show up in the Xml, and if I try:

```
$dlin = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
$dlin.Add("OtherField1")
$dlin.Add("OtherField2")
$values = @{LookupField = "NewShowField"; DepentantLookupInternalNames = $dlin}
```

I get the

> WARNING: No property 'DepentantLookupInternalNames' found on this field. Value will be ignored.
>   WARNING: No property 'LookupField' found on this field. Value will be ignored.

The property names should be correct as that is what Visual Studio Code tells me the property names are when I break point my code there. Is there a reference library for SharePoint Object properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you find about  'DependantLookupInternalNames ' there is no reference to this anywhere...let me know if i am missing something?

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia When I break point my code after I use Get-PnPField, I can see it as a property Generic.List in the variable description. I can open up the property and see any Columns I added by hand through SPO.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [FieldLookup properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee538609(v=office.15)), the property named "**DependentLookupInternalNames**".

And you can check the code of the Set-PnPField command.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Fields/SetField.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reference material there. So after reviewing it, looks as though this field is NOT editable via PowerShell PnP commands if I am looking at it correctly?

Comment: Did you try to use CSOM with PowerShell?